# Google Picasa search api

Tags: php, google-api, picasa

Can I search by keywords on Google Picasa by using API?

**UPD** Answer is - [List photos by community search](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/1.0/developers_guide_php#ListCommunityPhotos)

Answer (score 0):

here is the api docs from google

https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#SearchByTags

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for global search - https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#ListCommunityPhotos :)

Comment: Do you know, how to divide results into pages?